# iOS-8 Uitableviewcontroller with uitextfield keyboard appears while rotating device

Tags: uitableview, rotation, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation, uikeyboard

Using a

> `uitableviewcontroller`

to create a login form.

In 2 of the `UITableViewCells`  are login user name and password `UITextField` fields.

The keyboard is closed (never tapped a text field) and the device is rotated, the keyboard appears for a moment and then disappears from the bottom of the screen.

Is this a `iOS8` bug? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Looks strange.. never an ios8 bug.
you might be setting the first responder some where in

```
- (void)layoutSubviews or
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
```